# Cannot read property 'image' of undefined - image not rendering for only half of my docs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm running an aggregation query then passing the results to the client for different artist 'pages'. I have six total artists in my database but receive the below image error for only the three artists that *don't* have listed events:

```
TypeError: /Users/app/views/artists/show.ejs:4
    2| <div class="row">
    3|   <div class="col-6 shadow-sm">
 >> 4|       <% for(let img of artist.image ) { %>
    5|         <img src="<%= img.url %>" class="card-img-top img-thumbnail" alt="...">
    6|       <% } %>  
    7|     </div>

Cannot read property 'image' of undefined
    at eval (/Users/chaseschlachter/mtapp/views/artists/show.ejs:11:30)
```

The three that *do* have listed events render without any issue. Here's the function:

```
module.exports.showArtist = async (req, res,) => {
    const artistData = await Artist.findById(req.params.id).populate('events');
     if (!artistData) {
         req.flash('error', 'Cannot find that Artist');
         return res.redirect('/artists');
     }
 const artistDetails = await Event.aggregate([
    {
    "$match": {
    "artist": objectId(req.params.id)
    }
    },
    {
    $lookup: {
    from: "artists",
    let: {
    artistId: "$artist"
    },
    pipeline: [{
    $match: {
    $expr: {
    $and: [{
    $eq: ["$_id", "$$artistId"]
    }]
    }
    }
    }],
    as: "artist"
    }
    },
    {
    "$project": {
    "artist": {
    $arrayElemAt: ["$artist", 0]
    },
    "event": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "event_name": "$event_name",
    "venue_name": "$venue_name",
    "address": "$address",
    "description": "$description",
    "type": "$type",
    "created": "$created",
    "event_start": "$event_start",
    "event_end": "$event_end",
    "notification": "$notification",
    "totalGuests": { $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$guests" }, then: { $size: "$guests" }, else: 0 } },
    "attendedGuests": {
    "$size": {
    "$filter": {
    "input": "$guests",
    "as": "guest",
    "cond": {
    "$and": [{
    "$eq": ["$$guest.attended", "Y"]
    }]
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    
    }
    },
    {
    "$group": {
    "_id": "$artist._id",
    "email": {
    "$first": "$artist.email"
    },
    "location": {
    "$first": "$artist.location"
    },
    "image": {
    "$first": "$artist.image"
    },
    "genre": {
    "$first": "$artist.genre"
    },
    "about": {
    "$first": "$artist.about"
    },
    "size": {
    "$first": "$artist.size"
    },
    "venmo": {
    "$first": "$artist.venmo"
    },
    "events": {
    "$push": "$event"
    }
    }
    },
    ]);
const artist = artistDetails[0]
res.render('artists/show', { artist });
};
```

Why is it tripping up on artists without events?

Comment: `artistDetails` is most likely an empty array

Comment: Thanks @skara9 but all the other variables in `artistDetails` are passing through and the image variable works on half of the artists so it has data that works.

Comment: Yeah, it is empty for only the artist ids that aren't working. You need to debug - maybe log the `artistData` and `artistDetails` on each request

Comment: Thanks that's helpful - they're both full of data. `artistData` shows the artists' doc from the db and `artistDetails` shows an empty array for artists w/out events but the array defined in the aggregation for artists with events (w/ events array as a subdoc). `artistDetails[0]` shows each event w/ the variables I need. The problem is.. I'm querying into each artist by event so artists w/out events dont return data. How do I fix that part?